# Game Rejected by AppStoreConnect. [Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage]

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, review

This Is the
[image: reason] that my game was rejected in AppStoreConnect.

I ask users permission but I can't determine what user choose, allow or deny.

So question is that "How to determine users answer, and if it's DENY, what code I must write so my unity ads do not track that user".

Comment: How do you ask permission ? You must pass a completion handler to process the user choice .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an app store developer support question.

Comment: This is unfortunately the wrong place to ask questions about app store rejections.

Comment: This Question not belong to programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to unity ads.

You have a webview that opens a website that ask for get cookies without asking.

Comment: IOS was reject my app too. Unity ads display cookie collect but my app create with flutter and not have any feature using web view. Just a simple app